# redundant eval $(opam env) needed in Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, coq, opam

I successfully installed `coqc` with `Dockerfile`. Why do I need to run `eval $(opam env)` **again** when I execute the docker?

```
##############
#            #
# image name #
#            #
##############
FROM ubuntu:22.04

#################
#               #
# bash > sh ... #
#               #
#################
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

##########
#        #
# update #
#        #
##########
RUN apt-get update -y

############################
#                          #
# minimal set of utilities #
#                          #
############################
RUN apt-get install curl -y
RUN apt-get install libgmp-dev -y

###########################################
#                                         #
# opam is the easiest way to install coqc #
#                                         #
###########################################
RUN apt-get install opam -y
RUN opam init --disable-sandboxing
RUN eval $(opam env)

#########################################
#                                       #
# install coqc, takes around 10 minutes #
#                                       #
#########################################
RUN opam pin add coq 8.15.2 -y
```

Here is how I use it:

```
$ docker build --tag host --file .\Dockerfile.txt .
$ docker run -d -t --name my_lovely_docker host
$ docker exec -it my_lovely_docker bash
```

And when I'm inside the docker:

```
root@3055f16a1d78:/# coqc --version
bash: coqc: command not found
root@3055f16a1d78:/# eval $(opam env)
[WARNING] Running as root is not recommended
root@3055f16a1d78:/# coqc --version
The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.15.2
compiled with OCaml 4.13.1
```

Comment: Each `RUN` command runs in a temporary container, and any environment variables that get set are reset at the end of the container.  For a similar problem in a different language, see [condas `source activate virtualenv` does not work within Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945759/condas-source-activate-virtualenv-does-not-work-within-dockerfile); for this setup, [Run bash then eval command on Docker container startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70888834/run-bash-then-eval-command-on-docker-container-startup) may resolve your actual issue.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks, I tried adding `ENTRYPOINT ["opam", "exec", "--"]` at the end of the Dockerfile just like that other post suggested, but it didn't work. I got this error: `Error response from daemon: Container a51..b80 is not running` although it *is* running, and without the `ENTRYPOINT` line it does work ...

Comment: Instead of `RUN eval $(opam env)`, try `RUN opam env >> /root/.bashrc`

Comment: Most paths of running a Docker container don't read shell dotfiles like `.bashrc`; many containers (especially Alpine-based ones) don't include GNU bash at all.

Comment: OP is running [docker exec -it my_lovely_docker `bash`]

Comment: BTW is there any reason why you don't use the official docker-coq images? https://github.com/coq-community/docker-coq (which, among others, address the warning "Running as root is not recommended" you got)

Comment: @ErikMD yes, this Dockerfile also serves as a "rough guide" for native installations, so I want to make is as explicit as possible"

Comment: Thanks @tripleee for finding that duplicate! (anyway, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72678903/9164010) I just posted includes 1 more solution , related to `--auto-setup` / `--login`)

Comment: FWIW, it was suggested by @DavidMaze in one of the first comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Prebuilt versions of Coq (within Debian)

As mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72583938/redundant-eval-opam-env-needed-in-dockerfile#comment128295717_72583938), the [Docker-Coq](https://github.com/coq-community/docker-coq) repository gathers prebuilt versions of Coq, e.g.:

```bash
docker pull coqorg/coq:8.15.2
```

The list of all tags is available at this URL:

https://hub.docker.com/r/coqorg/coq#supported-tags

and the related documentation is in this Wiki:

https://github.com/coq-community/docker-coq/wiki

### A self-contained Dockerfile as an "installation tutorial" for Ubuntu

To address [the specific use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72583938/redundant-eval-opam-env-needed-in-dockerfile/72678903?noredirect=1#comment128373711_72583938) mentioned by the OP, here is a comprehensive Dockerfile that solves the main issue mentioned in the question (*Why do I need to run `eval $(opam env)` again when I execute the docker*), along with several fixes that are necessary to comply with standard Dockerfile and opam guidelines (though don't hinder the use case at stake):

```bash
##############
#            #
# image name #
#            #
##############
FROM ubuntu:22.04

#################
#               #
# bash > sh ... #
#               #
#################
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]

############################
#                          #
# minimal set of utilities #
#                          #
############################
# Run the following as root:
RUN apt-get update -y -q \
 && apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \
    # alphabetical order advised for long package lists to ease review & update
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    libgmp-dev \
    m4 \
    ocaml \
    opam \
    rsync \
    sudo \
#########################################
#                                       #
# Docker-specific cleanup to earn space #
#                                       #
#########################################
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#####################
#                   #
# add non-root user #
# (with sudo perms) #
#                   #
#####################
ARG coq_uid=1000
ARG coq_gid=${coq_uid}
RUN groupadd -g ${coq_gid} coq \
 && useradd --no-log-init -m -s /bin/bash -g coq -G sudo -p '' -u ${coq_uid} coq \
 && mkdir -p -v /home/coq/bin /home/coq/.local/bin \
 && chown coq:coq /home/coq/bin /home/coq/.local /home/coq/.local/bin

###########################################
#                                         #
# opam is the easiest way to install coqc #
#                                         #
###########################################
USER coq
WORKDIR /home/coq
RUN opam init --auto-setup --yes --bare --disable-sandboxing \
 && opam switch create system ocaml-system \
 && eval $(opam env) \
 && opam repo add --all-switches --set-default coq-released https://coq.inria.fr/opam/released \
#########################################
#                                       #
# install coqc, takes around 10 minutes #
#                                       #
#########################################
 && opam pin add -y -k version -j "$(nproc)" coq 8.15.2 \
#########################################
#                                       #
# Docker-specific cleanup to earn space #
#                                       #
#########################################
 && opam clean -a -c -s --logs

###################################
#                                 #
# Automate the 'eval $(opam env)' #
#                                 #
###################################
ENTRYPOINT ["opam", "exec", "--"]
CMD ["/bin/bash", "--login"]
```

### Summary of changes between both Dockerfiles / related remarks

In the Dockerfile above, the following fixes have been applied:

- Merge consecutive `RUN` commands with `&&` to avoid the issue raised in this SO question: [Purpose of specifying several UNIX commands in a single RUN instruction in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59535818/9164010).
- Add CLI flags `-q` and `--no-install-recommends` to `apt-get` commands, so that the output is less verbose, and the installed packages only include those specified (and mandatory dependencies).
- Put the APT packages in alphabetical order, to ease review and update.
- Add a non-root user (named `coq` here) so that `opam` does not complain anymore with the usual `[WARNING] Running as root is not recommended`.
  Of course, this step can be skipped in a non-Docker installation as we always have some regular `$USER` installed on a standard workstation…
- Replace the `opam init` command with:

  ```bash
  opam init --auto-setup --yes --bare --disable-sandboxing \
  && opam switch create system ocaml-system
  ```

  so the `~/.profile` script is updated automatically (thanks to `--auto-setup`) and the name of the switch (`system`) and its content (`ocaml-system`) is explicit.
- Add `opam repo add --all-switches --set-default coq-released https://coq.inria.fr/opam/released` so that one can then install community packages if need be, e.g.:

  ```bash
  opam install -y -v -j "$(nproc)" coq-mathcomp-ssreflect
  ```
- Pass the `-j "$(nproc)"` option to parallelize and speedup the installation, depending on the number of cores of the ambient system.
- Add optional, *Docker-specific* commands `apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and `opam clean -a -c -s --logs` to reduce the size of the Docker layers.

### Answer to the main issue raised in the question

- Each time a new shell (or a `RUN` command, etc.) is launched, the `eval $(opam env)` command is necessary to update the `PATH` etc.
- There are two ways to ensure that this command `eval $(opam env)` is done *automatically*:

  - either wrap the command with `opam exec -- …`
  - or run `/bin/bash --login`, so that the `~/.profile` init script is sourced (indeed, thanks to `opam init --auto-setup`, a line in charge of initializing the ambient shell with proper environement variables and so on, was appended by `opam` in this script).
- For completeness, both solutions have been implemented in this proposed Dockerfile (and we can just keep both without any specific drawback).

### To test all this

```bash
$ docker build -t coq-image .
# or better $ docker build -t coq-image --build-arg=coq_uid="$(id -u)" --build-arg=coq_gid="$(id -g)" .

$ docker run --name=coq -it coq-image
# or to mount the current directory
# $ docker run --name=coq -it -v "$PWD:$PWD" -w "$PWD" coq-image

  # Ctrl+D

$ docker start -ai coq  # to restart the container

  # Ctrl+D

$ docker rm coq         # to remove the container
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer, I learned a lot from it.